# "F is undefined" using live events

Tags: jquery, events

I'm getting an error off this and I'm assuming its in my syntax.

**Objective:** If a User doesn't actually write anything in the text_area, then fill it back in with its label.

**The Code:**

```
$(".card_signup_form input").live('click', function(){
  $(this).css("color","#666666");
  $old_value = $(this).attr("value");
  $(this).attr("value", "")
  if ( $(this).live('keyup blur') && $(this).attr("value") == "" ) {
    $(this).attr("value", $old_value);
  };
});
```

**jQuery's Common Sense Error:**

```
F is undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is here

```
  if ( $(this).live('keyup blur') ... ) {
   ...
  };
```

Live is looking for a function, AKA "F", to bind which you have not provided. I would suggest separating your live binds into individual code blocks.

As has been pointed out by others, just binding on click wont work for users who navigate without a mouse.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I typically handle this problem, you've got a lot of `live` events going on - not sure if you're adding new text fields to the DOM constantly, or not.  If so, might have to take a slightly different approach.

```
$('input').focus(function()
{
    $(this).data('prev-val', $(this).val())
})
.blur(function()
{
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0)
    {
        $(this).val( $(this).data('prev-val') );
    }
});
```

Comment: `blur` is the `onblur` event, which has been around for a long time. you'd shock and surprise me if you told me it didn't work on ie.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing by just specifying an blur and focus event handlers (focus will handle the click). You can also specify a "default" attribute and compare the value to the default. I would also specify a "default" css class rather than dealing directly with the attributes (just my pref).

```
$(".card_signup_form input").live("focus", function()
{
     var $this = $(this);
     if($this.val() != $this.attr("default"))
     {
         $this.val("");
         $this.removeClass("default");
     }
}).live("blur", function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
     if($this.val() == "")
     {
         $this.val($this.attr("default"));
         $this.addClass("default");
     }
}
<style>
.default{
   color:#666666;
}
</style>
```